# What is the best way to map a one to many relationship between `ApplicationUser` and its data in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

To define a one to many relationship between for example, an **artist** and an **album**, I would create two scaffolded items from the two models/classes below:

```
public class Album
{
     public int AlbumID { get; set; }
     [Display(Name="Album Title")]
     public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Artist")]
     public int ArtistID { get; set; }
     public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Artist")]
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Album>  Album { get; set; }
}
```

That would generate a `Create.cshtml` view (among others) for `Album`, with a drop-down list of **artists**.

---

Now I have an application with an `Image` model and an `ApplicationUser` model defining a relationship where each **application user** can upload many **images**.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
        public string UserSurname { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Image>  Image { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Image
{
     public int ImageID { get; set; }
     [Display(Name="Caption")]
     public string ImageCaption { get; set; }
     public int NumOfLikes { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Image")]
     public byte ImageFile { get; set; }
     // WHERE THE ApplicationUser FOREIGN KEY SHOULD BE
     public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
 }
```

---

Now my problem is that I don't know how to use `ApplicationUser`'s key as a foreign key in the `Image` model as I did in the `Album` model for `Artist`. A user should be able to upload an image without having to select his or her name from a drop-down list of users. That is, every **image** that a user uploads can only belong to that current **Identity User**.

## Questions

1. What is the best way to map a relationship between `ApplicationUser`
   and `Image` where every image uploaded by a user can only belong to
   that user (therefore no drop-down list)?
2. How would I return `ApplicationsUser`'s `UserFirstName` and `UserSurname` in `Image`'s **index** view (displaying the name and surname instead of the username associated with each image displayed)?

Comment: So what's wrong with adding int AppUserId to Image? And using Image.ApplicationUser.UserFirstName? Is it because you rely on the scaffolding for your views?

Comment: @Andy, I thought that there would be a different way of mapping the relationship, I am not sure how Entity Framework would treat `public int ApplicationUserID { get; set;}` since I don't know what the user id property is called or if it even matters. I'm under the assumption that the FK property should be identical to the PK property. I'm not sure I understand your second question. Because I am fairly new to ASP.NET, I want to limit the code that I have to write to minimize debugging. I want Entity Framework to do what its good at. I do know how to create my own views, but I would rather edit.

Comment: Well, you can always look in the aspnetusers table to find the key name. Then use that in Image. Pretty sure the default scaffolding has one approach with FKs, so if you don't want that, you'll have to modify it after, or start your own from scratch.